# Colocar la misma imagen en varios jframe

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, jframe

Tengo un programa con unos 10 jframe, y tengo que poner en todos un logo, que consta de un titulo y una imagen.
Pensaba crear un ojeto( no se si jpanel, jframe..) y agregarlo a los jframe del programa, pero no se como se hace.
Uso netbeans para programar, me gustaria hacer esto desde la parte de diseño de netbeans, para poder colocar el logo a mi gusto

Comment: nadie? una ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0):

Podes crear una clase visual que herede de JPanel, luego la abris en modo visual y le agregas el JLabel de título y el de imagen. Luego creas un instancia de esta nueva clase para cada JFrame y la agregas en cada uno.